# Using sizeof... within std::enable_if

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, enable-if

The following code does not compile, and I just can't figure out why.

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Ts) > 0>::type func() {
  // nop
}
```

The error message produced is:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
 typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Ts) > 0u>::type func() {
                                         ^
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need parentheses for this to be parsed correctly by the compiler:

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Ts) > 0)>::type func() {
                        ^                 ^
  // nop
}
```

Comment: Can you give an explanation, please?

Comment: @Incubbus I explain the rationale and give a smart ass solution in my answer

Answer (score 13):

The compiler interprets the right angle bracket (`>`) as a closing bracket for `std::enable_if`. This happens because once you begin a template parameter (or argument) list, the first time, the compiler, has the chance to close it (with `>`), it does so.

**Solution** (that proves the above point): Don't close the parameter list, reverse the condition and use a left angle bracket:

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
typename std::enable_if< 0 < sizeof...(Ts) >::type func() {}
//                         ^ compilers are cool with this
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1da1ca49cd0811fe)</kbd>